# Running asp page in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have runnning my asp.net application in IIS in order to test http and https. The problem is when I load the asp page, I get this error 'Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'SSLTest.Page1'.' I have build my solution and checked the framework version. Where am I going wrong?
[image: Error Message]

Comment: It could be that the `.aspx` page does not contain valid markup.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Open the `.aspx` page. Are there errors in it? Do you have things like tags that are never closed? Attributes that are not correct? Things like that.

Comment: I have rebuild it. There are no errors, when I load this page then this error comes 'Could not load type 'SSLTest.Page1'.'

Comment: Open the `.aspx` in Visual Studio. Are there any errors?

Comment: As I said, there are no errors

Comment: Do you have the code-behind class `SSLTest.Page1`?

Comment: Are you moving the code to IIS or the publish file? to publish to IIS, Right click on your Web Application from Solution Explorer then click publish, then copy the published files to IIS, sorry if my answer if obvious .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.aspx` file is inheriting from a class in your website's assembly file (the `.dll` file), this is your "code-behind class".

Not only does the `.dll` file need to be in the `bin` folder at the root of your application, but you also need to define an "Application Scope" within IIS that tells it where in the filesystem, an application begins. In this case you've got a folder called "`SSLProject\SSLTest`" within your IIS website root. You need to open IIS Manager and right-click the `SSLTest` folder and choose "Convert to Application", then it will work.

Alternatively, move your `bin` folder to the root of your website, though this may break any other applications you have deployed.

Comment: Chances are that the OP renamed the codebehind class but didn't update the `inherits` attribute to reflect the new name.

Comment: I put the bin folder to the root and it did worked. Thank You

Comment: But now my button click event does not work. I have just set the session value in page load and displaying the session value in the label. But nothing happens.

Comment: That's because you're probably using Application-root-relative "`~\`" paths in your application. Because you haven't set the IIS Application scope it means your application root is now different.